# How can I find a specific character, and return it's position in a txt file in c?

Tags: c

I am trying to build a snake game, where the 'O' represents the snake, and with every move the map is printed but with the 'O' changing position. So far I am trying to find and return the position of the 'O' within the starting map, which is a txt file as follows:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX                                                                    
X          X                                                                    
X O 5    1 X                                                                    
X          X                                                                    
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

This is my code so far:

```
#include "snake.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int find (FILE *level) {
    int i = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    char line [81];
    char line1;
    while (fgets(line, 81, level) != 0) {
        fscanf (level, "%s", &line1);
        if (line1 == 'O') {
            pos = i;
        }
        i++;    
    }
    return pos;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    FILE *level;
    level = fopen("../1.txt", "r");
    printf ("%d\n", find(level));
    fclose (level);
    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting a segmentation fault, even though I have used the same syntax before. Any ideas?

Comment: First do you understand what fscanf with %s does?

Comment: It scans the lines for a char.

Comment: `fgets` never returns `EOF`. If you ignore warnings, this is what you get.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake there when writing my question, it's supposed to be a 0

Comment: fscanf with %s does not "scan the lines for a char." Char is %c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the line with `fgets`, you can use `strchr` to search for the symbol. If it finds it `return i;`:

```
int find (FILE *level) {
    int i = 0;
    char line [81];
    while (fgets(line, 81, level) != 0) {
        if (strchr(line, 'O'))
            return i;
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

the whole program: https://ideone.com/7UMZyb

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `fgets` and then `fscanf`?  With the `fgets()` call you're effectively skipping every other line.  So you might want to rethink your logic there.

You are probably getting a segfault because `fscanf` with the `%s` conversion is trying to read a *string* including the null terminating byte, and you are passing it the address of a single char.  If you want to read one char use `%c`.

Note, your current logic will also only tell you (at best) what line the `'o'` is in, but not what column.  It might not tell you the correct row either if some of the lines are longer than 80 characters.

Comment: I have tried using fgets alone, and then using an index for line, but I get the same problem. %c didn't solve this either

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `sscanf(line, ...)` to actually scan the line your just read from the file?

Comment: well, then what do you propose? I can't return two different integers in the same method. I eventually want to move the O around, and multiply it depending on what number it crosses over